# General rules for identifying conditional sentences?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, sentence-patterns, syntactic-analysis, bare-conditional

I am trying to identify the subject and object in the following sentence:

> Come to me, and I'll give you a fight you'll never forget

At first, it appeared as if whenever a conjunction appears after a clause, and there's a future tense verb in the following clause, then it's a conditional sentence. My major problem here is whether this is a valid conditional sentence. Here, the speaker is actually saying

> I'm an interesting fighter

and not typically providing a condition for a result. I am trying to find out if there's any general rule for identifying a real conditional sentence. Could the rule that applies to this sentence be classified as one for identifying idioms? Thanks.

Comment: The speaker may be saying *I'm an interesting fighter,* but it is clearly a conditional construction, and the actual meaning is obtained by interpreting it metaphorically. You are not going to find grammar rules that tell you when to interpret a sentence metaphorically.

Comment: There are three clauses in the sentence, and each one has a subject. Which one were you looking for?

Comment: Exactly, @JohnLawler. My contention is that the above can be simplified to a single sentence with just a single subject and no object.

Comment: Then feel free to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement is conditional, and the second statement is not. The two sentences you have provided are ***not*** the same.

The first statement says, quite literally, that *if **you** come, then **I** will give you a fight you will never forget.* That is definitively conditional, as the speaker will only give the reader a "fight [he/she] will never forget" if the reader shows up.

The statement may imply that the speaker considers himself an interesting fighter, but that is a mere implication – it is not what the statement is literally saying. Conditional sentences are defined by their literal meaning and their structure, not by the implications behind the statements.

Comment: Yh, I understand. But what information do you think your brain stores with such a statement. It's definitely not the literal meaning. I guess I agree with your last statement and also with @Peter Shor that there are no rules for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OP's sentence is perfectly normal English. You can read it as starting with *[**If** you] come to me...*, but I don't think it's necessarily helpful to assume that in all cases. Take, for example:

> *Come Christmas, the goose will have gotten fat*.

...where the "conditionality" is significantly different (it means ***when*** Christmas comes, not ***if***).

---

Obviously in OP's specific example, the "subject" is indeed an implied ***you***. Equally obviously, OP is mistaken in supposing it implies *I'm an interesting fighter*. It implies *I will beat you so severely you will never forget it* - because it will be such a traumatic experience, and/or you will bear the scars for the rest of your life.

Comment: I would argue the assertion that "Come Christmas" is not an "if" condition - "If it is Christmas, the goose will have gotten fat," or even "If Christmas has come, the goose will have gotten fat." "When" indicates that the writer knows with absolute certainty that the condition will be fulfilled, but it isn't necessary to add to the statement, grammatically speaking - all conditional statements (to my knowledge) can be rewritten with an "if".

Comment: @Cmillz: That's why I put "conditionality" in quotes - to indicate that it's *not* a standard "conditional" in the sense of ***if X is true*. But it *is* "conditional" in the sense of *condition X does not yet obtain, although it's certain to apply in the future*. It gets a bit more convoluted with *"Come rain or shine, I'll be there"*, since semantically there's absolutely *no conditionality at all* in such a statement.

Comment: Eh, you're over implying things IMO. In your case, you think what makes a fight interesting is the brutality of the fight, but *never forget* IMO means remarkable or simply, *interesting*. Also, I'm confused whether you are validating my claim or the other way round. I'm trying to say that in that type of example, it can never really be a typical conditional statement. Both examples you gave for instance are metaphoric.

Comment: In the phrase "Come rain or shine", there is a condition, though that condition is definitively true. "Come Christmas, the goose will have gotten fat" is absolutely a conditional phrase that can be rewritten using "if", and so can "Come rain or shine" (If there is rain or shine).

Comment: @Chibueze: I'm a native speaker, and I'm guessing you're not. You should note that even when the "gift" isn't explicitly identified, [I'll give you something you won't forget](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'll+give+you+something+you+won't+forget%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) almost always means *a beating* or similar extreme punishment. Only one out of about 30 written instances there is "memorable" for some other reason. When the "gift" is explicitly named as "a fight", there can be no other feasible interpretation.

Comment: Yh, I thought so after you said it. I wondered what else would make a fight unforgettable if not that, but if the listener is stronger then the person, then they're just bragging and the statement would mean *I'm a strong fighter*. Thanks for that input. I think I know what to do now.

Comment: @Chibueze: There are several related idiomatic usages in this general area. Parent to bawling child: [Stop that, or I'll give you something to cry about!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'll+give+you+something+to+cry+about%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example. And the standard threat: [I'll give you what for!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'll+give+you+what+for%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Answer (score 0):

*Come to me, and I'll give you a fight you'll never forget*.

The subject of the example sentence above is *you* because a 2nd person command forms the conditional clause (subjects get dropped with commands). It's perfectly fine to use the imperative to form the condition, and identifying what the speaker might be implying does not change that (i.e., that he is an "interesting fighter").

You could also use the present indicative for the first clause:

*If you come to me, I'll give you a good fight.*

*If* is also a conjunction, so the conjunction does not have to follow the condition, and there are a variety of other verb tenses and moods that can be used in either clause. It is not one rule, but a system of rules in that determines the verb tense and mood. Following an imperative statement with the future tense is just one way of forming a conditional

You could also use the subjunctive followed by the conditional, though sometimes you wind up with a more poetic or slightly archaic sound:

*If I were a fighter, I'd fight you.*
*If you were to come to me, I'd give you a fight that you'd never forget.*

The subjunctive is falling out of favor in English though, so you might try the simple past tense for the condition:

*If I fought you, I would put you in the hospital.*

You can find many other examples off-site. You could try the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences) on conditional sentences in English or scan through university pages for examples, being careful to verify the source if you are concerned about having authoritative information: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm